# Angular Routing not populating ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have an issue were my routing is not populating my view.

I have the following code running from an Xampp local server:

angular 1.4.9

**index.html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js" type="javascript/text"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Ng-Route.js" type="javascript/text"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js" type="javascript/text"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**user.html:**

```
<div>
  <fieldset>
    Hello, {{ctrl.message}}
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'user.html',
            controller  : 'controller as ctrl'
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

app.controller('controller', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.message = 'Everyone';
  });
```

I have absolutely no clue why this is failing, nothing shows up on the page. I am expecting "Hello, Everyone".

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: can you check network and console in developer tools for errors?

Comment: The console shows no errors

Comment: Everything looks normal in dev tools, all scripts are loading and no errors are logging.

Comment: Works here http://plnkr.co/edit/PXswypPGy6wuwhiHQbJV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for looking @YuryTarabanko, I think it may be an issue with how the scripts are loading locally on my machine

Answer (score 1):

You had mistaken declaring your controller on your route. `controller` does accept controller name in `string`/`controller function`. And use `controllerAs` option to alias your controller.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'user.html',
        controller  : 'controller',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has made no difference, I do prefer this syntax though so thanks.

Comment: OPs version actually works. The problem should be somewhere else. http://plnkr.co/edit/PXswypPGy6wuwhiHQbJV?p=preview

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks for heads up, I actually looked at [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L76) and suggested that change for OP.